Need to give a color to a menu link in html css
Please find the code for navbar below. How can I give the color to the html link like Home, Services and About?
   <!--navbar-->
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <div class="navimg">
    
      <img src="./img/Heliosupdated.png" alt="Description">

    </div>
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-                 target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     /button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>

     </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>

I am expecting the color to be changed once the external CSS is being applied.
I tried to give this external css as mentioned below, I have tried to change the color. It won't affect without adding an important! in the code.
.nav-link active a {
   color:#2762AC;
}

Please find the css below,

.navbar-nav {
    margin-left: auto;
}


.nav-link active a {
    color:#2762AC !important;
  }


/*Navbar style*/


/* end of Navbar style*/
/* end of Navbar style*/


#navbarNav{
    
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-right: 240px;

}

.navimg img{
    width:100%;
    height: 97px;
}


use !important in your external css file
.nav-link active a {
  color:#2762AC !important;
}


Using !important is a last resort.  CSS Specificity should be used if possible

Despite an answer already been accepted and upvoted, it looks like your CSS selector has a couple of errors, which would mean the !important wouldn't have any effect.
.nav-link active a means you're looking for an <a> element within an <active> element within an element with the nav-link class.
According to your HTML, you're actually looking for an <a> element which has both classes of nav-link and active... which would suggest you actually want...
a.nav-link.active {
  color: #2762AC;
}


One note on the use of !important is that it should be considered a last resort.
Instead you should utilise CSS Specificity if possible, where the calculated "weight" of your CSS selector is taken into account.

In response to the comment by the OP...

But this doesn't work. I have to use important

Then what you have provided is not a valid example of what is going on, and there is little we can do without a minimal reproducable example.
Here is your code (with a correction on the </button> typo) with your CSS and my CSS in a runnable snippet. Note how that even with !important the link is not green, it's red...


/* Your CSS */
.nav-link active a {
   color:green !important;
}
/* My CSS */
a.nav-link.active {
   color:red;
}
<!--navbar-->
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <div class="navimg">
    
      <img src="./img/Heliosupdated.png" alt="Description">

    </div>
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-                 target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button> <!-- Typo Fixed -->
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>

     </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>




Using the CSS pasted into a comment by the OP, it still doesn't work, the link does not change colour...

But this doesn't work. I have to use important



/* Your CSS */
.navbar-nav { margin-left: auto; } .nav-link active a { color:#2762AC !important; } /*Navbar style*/ /* end of Navbar style*/ /* end of Navbar style*/ #navbarNav{ padding-top: 70px; padding-right: 240px; } .navimg img{ width:100%; height: 97px; }
<!--navbar-->
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <div class="navimg">
    
      <img src="./img/Heliosupdated.png" alt="Description">

    </div>
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-                 target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button> <!-- Typo Fixed -->
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>

     </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>




But this doesn't work. I have to use important. Else kindly run on your system and let me know. thanks

Then the example you have given is wrong, or you have other things happening in your CSS.  Without a [mcve] there is nothing I can do.  But I stand by my answer that based on what you've provided the !important shouldn't work

please find the complete css regarding Nav in my external sheet.
.navbar-nav {
margin-left: auto;
}
.nav-link active a {
color:#2762AC !important;
}
/Navbar style/
/* end of Navbar style*/
/* end of Navbar style*/
#navbarNav{
padding-top: 70px;
padding-right: 240px;

}
.navimg img{
width:100%;
height: 97px;
}

Pasting code in comments is not useful, all this information should be part of your original question.  However, even taking a copy of it, and putting it into the code i've just added to my answer, it is not changing the colour.

It's mentioned in the comment now but please give me the solution of it.

I have given you the solution... if I cannot replicate what you're seeing, please explain to me exactly what I'm supposed to do?  Please stop moving the accepted answer tick, pick an answer and stick with it.  If the !important answer works, then stay with that, but why it works makes no sense to me based on the information provided.  I've wasted enough time on this, good luck

I just want you to change to any color without important! . But right now I have ticked important as it's working.  I think you haven't wasted the time, at last you are helping the community and improving your ranking or skill as well.

If you wish to improve my ranking, please consider upvoting my answer.  Good luck with the rest of your project

sure, thanks a lot.
